# Probability of independent random variables X, Y and 1 form a triangle

Tags: probability

Random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent. $X$ density function - $p_X(t)=\frac{t}{2}\cdot I_{[0;2]}$ (where $I$ is indicator function on $[0;2]$). $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $[0;3]$. Find the probability that a segment with lengths X,Y,1 can make a triangle.

I started to find the probability of 3 reversed cases: $1-p(\Delta)=p(Y\leq 1-X) + p(Y\leq X-1) + p(Y\geq X+1)$ but do not understand (lack of theory possibly, learning by myself) how to calculate this probabilities.

**Update:**

I even found somebody's solution, but can`t get how these integrals appeared:
$\int_0^3\frac{t}{2}\frac{1-t}{3}dt+\int_1^2\frac{t}{2}\frac{t-1}{3}dt+\int_0^2\frac{t}{2}\frac{2-t}{3}dt$

Comment: It often helps to visual this kind of thing.  Maybe start with the $[0,2] \times [0,3]$ rectangle, that being the possible values of $(X,Y)$, and visualize which parts you want or don't want, then do the integral inside the areas?

Comment: @antkam, what can you tell about a solution integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the probabilities $\ p(Y\leq 1-X)\ $, $\ p(Y\leq X-1)\ $, and $\ p(Y\geq X+1)\ $, you have to integrate the joint density function $\ \frac{x}{2}\frac{1}{3}\ $ of $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ over the regions in the. $x$-$y$ plane representing these inequalities. These are shown in blue, green and red, respectively, in the diagram below. Call these regions $\ B\ $, $\ G\ $, and $\ R\ $:
$$\ B=\left\{\,\left(x,y\right)\vert\,x\ge 0, y\ge 0, y\le 1-x\,\right\}\ ,$$
$$\ G=\left\{\,\left(x,y\right)\vert\,0\le x\le 2, y\ge 0, y\le x-1\,\right\}\ ,$$
$$\ R=\left\{\,\left(x,y\right)\vert\,x\ge 0, x+1\le y\le 3\,\right\}\ .$$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
p(Y\leq 1-X) &=& \iint_B \frac{x}{6}dydx\\
&=& \int_0^1\hspace{-0.6em}\int_0^{1-x}\frac{x}{6}dydx\\
&=& \int_0^1 \frac{x\left(1-x\right)}{6}dx\\
&=& \frac{1}{36}
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
p(Y\leq X-1) &=& \iint_G \frac{x}{6}dydx\\
&=& \int_1^2\hspace{-0.6em}\int_0^{x-1}\frac{x}{6}dydx\\
&=& \int_1^2 \frac{x\left(x-1\right)}{6}dx\\
&=& \frac{5}{36}
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
p(Y\geq X+1) &=& \iint_R \frac{x}{6}dydx\\
&=& \int_0^2\hspace{-0.6em}\int_{x+1}^3\frac{x}{6}dydx\\
&=& \int_0^2 \frac{x\left(2-x\right)}{6}dx\\
&=& \frac{2}{9}
\end{eqnarray}
So $\ p\left(\Delta\right) = 1 - \frac{1}{36}-\frac{5}{36}-\frac{2}{9} =\frac{11}{18}
.$

As an alternative, it's a little easier to calculate  $\ p\left(\Delta\right) = p\left(\,\{X+Y>1\}\, \&\, \{X+1>Y\}\,\&\, \{Y+1>X\}\ \right) $ directly, by integrating the density function over the region coloured grey in the diagram (call it $\ D\ $):
\begin{eqnarray}
p\left(\Delta\right) &=& \iint_D \frac{x}{6}dydx\\
&=& \int_0^1\frac{x}{6}\int_{1-x}^{x+1} dydx+\int_1^2\frac{x}{6}\int_{x-1}^{x+1} dydx\\
&=& \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{3}+\int_1^2\frac{x}{3}dx\\
&=& \frac{11}{18}\ ,
\end{eqnarray}
as before.
[image]

Comment: Wow! Many thanks! Did not expect such a detailed explanation. Now it gets much clear to me.